# Divide a set of items XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-3.0

I am new to XPath so do not know much. I have been googling for a bit and cannot find anything, maybe I am just searching the wrong thing but I thought I would ask on here.

I am currently trying to `divide` a `set of numbers`, `(100, 200, 300)`, all by the `same value`. So I want: `100/2, 200/2, 300/2`. I initially assumed it would be something like: `//products/price div 2`, but this would try and `divide` the actual set itself by 2 instead of the items

How would I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: What version of XPath? What language/tool do you use XPath in?

Comment: I am using oXygen and version 3 of XPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath 3.0 has [`for` expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-for-expressions):

```
for $n in (100, 200, 300) return $n div 2
```

returns a sequence of

```
(50, 100, 150)
```

as requested.